# Remove nested object from Backbone model

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-model

I have a `backbone.js` model with nested objects for `fieldData` as shown in image below.

I know I can remove whole attribute like this:

```
this.unset('fieldData');
```

But how do I remove an individual objects (eg:- `dataPartnerCodes`) in that attribute.

Does **backbone** provide any tools for this?

[image]

Comment: did you try to update the fieldData Array with a modified copy?
`fieldData = this.get('fieldData');
fieldData[5]['fieldName'] = 'anotherDataPartnerCode';
this.set('fieldData', fieldData);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone itself doesn't have such instruments but you can create a method for easy model usage.

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  // Remove by passed index
  removeFieldDataAt : function (index) {
    var fieldData = this.get('fieldData');
    fieldData.splice(index, 1);
    this.set('fieldData', fieldData);
  }
});
var model = new Model({fieldData : [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}]});
model.removeFieldDataAt(1);
console.log(model.toJSON()); // [{id:1}, {id:3}]
```

Another example:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  removeFieldDataByCriteria : function (criteria) {
    var fieldData = this.get('fieldData');
    var fields = _.where(fieldData, criteria);
    _.each(fields.reverse(), function (field) {
      fieldData.splice(fieldData.indexOf(field), 1);
    });
    this.set('fieldData', fieldData);
  }
});
var model = new Model({fieldData : [{id:1,visible:true}, {id:2,visible:false}, {id:3,visible:true}]});
model.removeFieldDataByCriteria({visible:true});
console.log(model.toJSON()); // [{id:2, visible:false}]
```

Comment: Shouldn't this work without 'this.set('fieldData', fieldData)', because your are getting reference to array so you should not need to set it again?

Comment: In this case you will update your model silently without `change` event and this is not good.

Comment: @RuntimeException added another example